# R Time calculation get error

Tags: r, date, lubridate, calculation

I calculate the time and the code is:

```
x <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
y <- as.Date("2016-01-31")
z <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
w <- max(0,y-x)
w2 <- z-x
w/w2
```

However, I got the error:

```
Error in `/.difftime`(w, w2) : 
  second argument of / cannot be a "difftime" object
```

is there any way to figure out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert 'w2' to `numeric` as the `class` of it is `difftime`

```
w/as.numeric(w2)
#[1] 0.08196721
```